# Need trigger to run when change occurs within cell of a certain range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I have a spread sheet where users can update a cell's within Column 'J' with notes, however when they update that cell I need my script to run.
This will then copy all the information from Columns 'I' & 'J', and paste them into another cell, then put a Vlookup formula back into 'J' where it has just taken the information from.

It may sound a complicated way about going around things, but because I have various sheets pulling information from different workbooks I need it to happen in this way.

However I have tried numerous solutions and can not get it to run when a cell is changed.
I have tried a installable on change trigger, but this works on the whole workbook and often ends up deleting the information it should be copying.

I have pasted the code I am working in below, any help would be grateful.

```js
function onChange(e) 
{
  var editRange = { // J:J
    top : 2,
    bottom : 2000,
    left : 10,
    right : 10
  };

  // Exit if we're out of range
  var thisRow = e.range.getRow();
  if (thisRow < editRange.top || thisRow > editRange.bottom) return;

  var thisCol = e.range.getColumn();
  if (thisCol < editRange.left || thisCol > editRange.right) return;

  //Where Is The Data Stored That You Want To Copy
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("1ZQLKnCHD9acTXCKpTeOnJshHEz43FDPdKZ-U6Me-k_k")
  var West = ss.getSheetByName("West Orders")
  var WestNotes = ss.getSheetByName("West Notes")

  //Ranges of The Data You Want To Copy
  var CopyWestNotes = West.getRange(2, 9,West.getLastRow(),2).getValues()

    //Clear The Data Before Overiding
  var ClearNotes = WestNotes.getRange(2,1,WestNotes.getLastRow(),2).clear()

  //Ranges Of The Data You Want To Store
  var PasteWestId = WestNotes.getRange(2,1,West.getLastRow(),2).setValues(CopyWestNotes);

  //Put a formula in to update Notes;
  var formula = '=IFerror(VLOOKUP(i2,\'West Notes\'!A:B,2,false)," ")'
  var WestFormula = West.getRange(2,10,West.getLastRow(),1).setValue(formula)
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

## The onEdit event

The change trigger is not a simple trigger.  You have to install it yourself. There is also no e.range in this [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#change).  I would guess that if you had checked your executions that you would see some errors.

I modified your code to an onEdit() simple trigger. But you may have to make it installable if you're doing anything that requires permissions.  And it looks like you are.  So now you should be able to continue debugging your code.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var editRange = {top:2,bottom:2000,left:10,right:10};
  var thisRow=e.range.rowStart;
  if (thisRow<editRange.top || thisRow>editRange.bottom)return;
  var thisCol=e.range.columnStart;
  if (thisCol<editRange.left || thisCol>editRange.right)return;
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("id");
  var West = ss.getSheetByName("West Orders");
  var WestNotes = ss.getSheetByName("West Notes");
  var CopyWestNotes = West.getRange(2, 9,West.getLastRow(),2).getValues();
  var ClearNotes = WestNotes.getRange(2,1,WestNotes.getLastRow(),2).clear();
  var PasteWestId = WestNotes.getRange(2,1,West.getLastRow(),2).setValues(CopyWestNotes);
  var formula = '=IFerror(VLOOKUP(i2,\'West Notes\'!A:B,2,false)," ")';
  var WestFormula = West.getRange(2,10,West.getLastRow(),1).setValue(formula);
}
```

I should have mentioned that you'll need to add the id in line 7.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I have ran the ammended code you have kindly done for me, but when checking the execution log after editing a cell I still get the following message "Execution failed: TypeError: Cannot read property "rowStart" from undefined. (line 3, file "Code") "

Comment: Are you using an exact copy of my code including the `onEdit(e)`;

Comment: yes exact copy, but I should probably include the sheet I want to look at as well as the range in which the edit / change occurs

Comment: Well, somehow the event object is not being populated.  You'll either have to debug it yourself or share a spreadsheet that exhibits the problem so that I can figure it out.  If you used an installable trigger hopefully you chose an onEdit() trigger not an onChange() trigger.  And in fact if that's the problem I won't be able to see them because I can't see your project triggers.

Comment: A simple change to line 7 of the script has eradicated the problem, instead of using .openById, I used .getActiveSpreadsheet

Comment: This strangely seemed to of resolved it, I have no idea why, but thank you for all your help, It was appreciated

Comment: It worked because onEdit() is always working from the activeSheet. Please check off the answer and have a great day.

Answer (score 0):

A simple change to line 7 of the script has eradicated the problem, instead of using .openById, I used .getActiveSpreadsheet